# Custom Camera and Crop image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avfoundation, crop

I have created a custom camera and have implemented below code to crop the taken image, I have shown guides in the preview layer so I want to crop the image which appears in that area.

```
func imageByCropToRect(rect:CGRect, scale:Bool) -> UIImage {    
    var rect = rect
    var scaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    if scale  {
        scaleFactor = self.scale
        rect.origin.x *= scaleFactor
        rect.origin.y *= scaleFactor
        rect.size.width *= scaleFactor
        rect.size.height *= scaleFactor
    }

    var image: UIImage? = nil;
    if rect.size.width > 0 && rect.size.height > 0 {
        let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)
        image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
    }

    return image!
}
```

This code just works fine when & give the exact cropped image when the below line of code is commented, though I want the image streaming to be full screen so I have to use the below line of code. The image comes zoomed out sort of.

```
(self.previewLayer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
```

How do I solve this issue? Is the cropping code wrong?

Here is the full Class code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var guideImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var guidesView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraPreviewView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButtonView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var captureButton: UIButton!

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer: CALayer!
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice!

    /// This will be true when the user clicks on the click photo button.
    var takePhoto = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        previewLayer = CALayer()
        takePhoto = false

        requestAuthorization()
    }

    private func userinteractionToButton(_ interaction: Bool) {
        captureButton.isEnabled = interaction
    }

    /// This function will request authorization, If authorized then start the camera.
    private func requestAuthorization() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) {
        case .authorized:
            prepareCamera()

        case .denied, .restricted, .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video, completionHandler: { (granted) in
                if !Thread.isMainThread {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if granted {
                            self.prepareCamera()
                        } else {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "unable_to_access_the_Camera", message: "to_enable_access_go_to_setting_privacy_camera_and_turn_on_camera_access_for_this_app", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: {_ in
                                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                            }))
                            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if granted {
                        self.prepareCamera()
                    } else {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "unable_to_access_the_Camera", message: "to_enable_access_go_to_setting_privacy_camera_and_turn_on_camera_access_for_this_app", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: {_ in
                            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                        }))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    /// Will see if the primary camera is avilable, If found will call method which will asign the available device to the AVCaptureDevice.
    private func prepareCamera() {
        // Resets the session.
        self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices
            self.assignCamera(availableDevices)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            // development, need to test this on iOS 8
            if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) {
                self.assignCamera([availableDevices])
            } else {
                self.showAlert()
            }
        }
    }

    /// Assigns AVCaptureDevice to the respected the variable, will begin the session.
    ///
    /// - Parameter availableDevices: [AVCaptureDevice]
    private func assignCamera(_ availableDevices: [AVCaptureDevice]) {
        if availableDevices.first != nil {
            captureDevice = availableDevices.first
            beginSession()
        } else {
            self.showAlert()
        }
    }

    /// Configures the camera settings and begins the session, this function will be responsible for showing the image on the UI.
    private func beginSession() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
        self.cameraPreviewView.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        self.previewLayer.frame.origin.y = +self.cameraPreviewView.frame.origin.y
        (self.previewLayer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.previewLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.cameraPreviewView.clipsToBounds = true
        captureSession.startRunning()

        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.cameraPreviewView)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.cameraButtonView)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.guidesView)

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [((kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) as String):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.letsappit.camera")
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

        self.userinteractionToButton(true)
    }


    /// Get the UIImage from the given CMSampleBuffer.
    ///
    /// - Parameter buffer: CMSampleBuffer
    /// - Returns: UIImage?
    func getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer:CMSampleBuffer, orientation: UIImageOrientation) -> UIImage? {
        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer) {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
            let context = CIContext()
            let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))

            if let image = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: orientation)

            }

        }
        return nil
    }

    /// This function will destroy the capture session.
    func stopCaptureSession() {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
            for input in inputs {
                self.captureSession.removeInput(input)
            }
        }
    }

    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unable to access the camera", message: "It appears that either your device doesn't have camera or its broken", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {_ in
            self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func didTapClick(_ sender: Any) {
        userinteractionToButton(false)
        takePhoto = true
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showImage" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ShowImageViewController
            vc.image = sender as! UIImage
        }
    }
}

extension CameraViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        if connection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
            connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
        }

        if takePhoto {
            takePhoto = false

            // Rotation should be unlocked to work.
            var orientation = UIImageOrientation.up
            switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
            case .landscapeLeft:
                orientation = .left

            case .landscapeRight:
                orientation = .right

            case .portraitUpsideDown:
                orientation = .down

            default:
                orientation = .up
            }

            if let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer, orientation: orientation) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let newImage = image.imageByCropToRect(rect: self.guideImageView.frame, scale: true)
                    self.stopCaptureSession()
                    self.previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showImage", sender: newImage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view hierarchy image
[image]

Comment: Bear this in mind with your project: http://www.openradar.me/36292067

Comment: @Scriptable please have a look at my code, am not using the UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage.

Comment: best to explain as much as you can here, I shouldn't need to click elsewhere to understand your issue

Comment: @Scriptable I have build the camera app using AVCaptureSession, CALayer, AVCaptureDevice and then streaming the video on preview layer, once click button is presses am taking the image from CMSampleBuffer.

Comment: If you jsut have sometime free, you can go through the project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking people here for help, so you need to make it as easy as possible for people to help you.  Post as much detail as needed to answer the question (and no more).  Don't make us do any more work than we need to.  Referencing code outside the question doesn't work because that code can change at any time.

Comment: @ChrisGarrett I did what you adviced.

Comment: Okay, this is better, but we still need a bit more info.  Where are you calling the cropping function from?  It sounds like you're trying to do this for every frame of the preview, and that is going to be a major performance bottleneck if so.

Comment: @ChrisGarrett here I added the full class code and view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where the problem is.  I would either use the debugger or some print statements to figure out whether the issue is with the image or the view displaying the image.  Print out size of the cropped image to make sure it is correct.

Then, print out the image view size in the ShowImageViewController in viewDidAppear to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Okay I'll try to use the debugger and see the view hierarchy over there.

Answer (score 0):

For the correction of zooming out of cropped image, you have to change your crop function to this by using image orientation.

```
func croppedInRect(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    func rad(_ degree: Double) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(degree / 180.0 * .pi)
    }

    var rectTransform: CGAffineTransform
    switch imageOrientation {
    case .left:
        rectTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rad(90)).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -self.size.height)
    case .right:
        rectTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rad(-90)).translatedBy(x: -self.size.width, y: 0)
    case .down:
        rectTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rad(-180)).translatedBy(x: -self.size.width, y: -self.size.height)
    default:
        rectTransform = .identity
    }
    rectTransform = rectTransform.scaledBy(x: self.scale, y: self.scale)

    var cgImage = self.cgImage

    if cgImage == nil{

        let ciContext = CIContext()
        if let ciImage = self.ciImage{
            cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
        }
    }

    if let imageRef = cgImage?.cropping(to: rect.applying(rectTransform)){
        let result = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        return result
    }


    return nil

}
```