# Resize UIViews depending upon the screen size like in Android in iOS

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, autoresize

I have designed the below view using the constraints and it's been done on iPhone 6 in storyboard so it looks exactly the same on iPhone 6.
When I run it on iPhone 5s or SE all the views gets distorted. on iPhone X things get worse. I have knowledge of content hugging and content compression.

[image]

To overcome this issue what I do is I have created the below functions to resize the view depending upon the screen size.

```
import UIKit

/// The UI was desinged on this screen
let designedOnSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 568)

/// This is the phone screen.
let currentScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

func getVerticleCostraintValueFrom(_ constant: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    // cSize * (constant / size)
    return currentScreenSize.height*constant/designedOnSize.height
}

func reconfigureVerticleConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
    for constraint in constraints {
        constraint.constant = getVerticleCostraintValueFrom(constraint.constant)
    }
}

func getHorizontalCostraintValueFrom(_ constant: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    // cSize * (constant / size)
    return currentScreenSize.width*constant/designedOnSize.width
}

func reconfigureHorizontalConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
    for constraint in constraints {
        constraint.constant = getHorizontalCostraintValueFrom(constraint.constant)
    }
}

func configureFontSize(_ views: [Any]) {
    for view in views {
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            label.font = label.font.withSize(getHorizontalCostraintValueFrom(label.font.pointSize))
            continue
        }

        if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            textField.font = textField.font?.withSize(getHorizontalCostraintValueFrom(textField.font!.pointSize))
            continue
        }

        if let textView = view as? UITextView {
            textView.font = textView.font?.withSize(getHorizontalCostraintValueFrom(textView.font!.pointSize))
            continue
        }

        if let button = view as? UIButton {
            button.titleLabel?.font = button.titleLabel?.font.withSize(getHorizontalCostraintValueFrom(button.titleLabel!.font.pointSize))
            continue
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureFontSize([emailTextField, mobileNumberTextField, passwordTextField, signUpButton, orSignUpLabel, facebookButton, googleButton, twitterButton])
    reconfigureVerticleConstraints([logoTopConstraint, logoHeightConstraint, emailTextFieldHeightConstraint, emailTextFieldTopConstraint ........])
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Is the above way correct? If not, then please give me advice or suggest me some good practice as for me performance really matters. 
Will this affect the laying out of views?

In Android, this is automatically handled by the system such things can be done in iOS?

[image]

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to use the size of the screen to directly calculate your layout. This can be a problem when yet more screen sizes are introduced. You should use layout constraints that set the size and position of objects using multipliers or aspect ratio constraints.  E.g you could constrain the height of a button to be 1:5 to the height of the root view.

Comment: Storyboard constraints are used to make your design work on different screen sizes, that is the main purpose of them, so coding shouldn't be needed for simpler designs. Could you please show an example of what exactly goes wrong on different devices?

Comment: @Paulw11 that's very good idea, how do I calculate the ratio between the button and the view because as soon as I make button equal width to view it will take the view width and I won't get the exact size. Do you have any trick for this?

Comment: @Paulw11 Do we usually change the font size as well depending upon the phone sizes, not iPads, only phones. You see I have created one function for that as well. I think it's necessary as if the textField's height is set to 1:10 of the rootView then on iPhone 5 and all the height of the UITextField will decrease and I don't think it will decrease the size of the text inside.

Comment: @LGP on iPhone 5 the Google and Twitter button used to go outside the bounds of the screen if I don't give bottom constraints. If I give bottom constraint then the view to which I haven't set height used to vanish or shrink to depending upon the screen size and that used to result in bad UI.

Comment: You can set font scaling for your text fields.  You should also support dynamic type so that user preferences adjust your font sizes too

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay I'll give it a shot. If you don't mind there is a question I have posted which didn't receive many answers can you please see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302828/custom-camera-and-crop-image-in-swift and well I can provide you with my Github project link if you want to have closure look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can change the UI for login screen by adding social icons next to each other horizontally

With this you will not face the issue of resizing

ref: https://dribbble.com/shots/3803685-Fintech-App-UI